# Magento Category Images are all blurry after changing size within list.phtml

Tags: image, magento, caching, resize, blurry

http://www.rattanfurnitureuk.co.uk/sept2015/rattan-corner-sets.html

I have deleted the cache on the service but the images are still rendering blurry.

The images should be sharp and at 276 x 276px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Magento admin navigate to:

> System > Configuration > Catalog > Product Image

Update the **Small Image Width** field to 276px. Then flush image cache and refresh full page cache.

Answer (score 0):

Go to following location and open list.phtml file.

```
app\design\frontend\yourpackage\yourtheme\template\catalog\product\
```

and find the following line

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
```

In this code check

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135"
```

Try changing resize(135) and height and width also in above mentioned line.

**Update:** 
You have following html in your site.

```
  <a class="product-image" title="Maze Rattan - Winchester Square Corner Group" href="http://www.rattanfurnitureuk.co.uk/sept2015/rattan-corner-sets/maze-rattan-winchester-square-corner-group.html">

    <img width="135" height="135" alt="Maze Rattan - Winchester Square Corner Group" src="http://www.rattanfurnitureuk.co.uk/sept2015/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/135x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/3/1/3198.jpg">

</a>
```

Check what is there in  `<img` tag.

Comment: <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"> - Thats all I have in there...

Comment: @Ryan There must be an ending </a> tag and in between some code. Check updated answer.

Comment: @Ryan Try solution suggested by WombleGold